# Finding a syntax error in a large VBA/MS Access project

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access database that displays an error message about a SQL syntax error on launch. "Syntax Error in query. Incomplete query clause." It also shows another error a few seconds after I hit "OK" on the first one.

Here's the two errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qb3t.jpg

But it doesn't tell me where the syntax error is. There are SQL statements in a bunch of different places all over this project. This is a really large project and it wouldn't be practical to just look through all the code hoping that I notice an error someplace. How can I find out where this error is?

EDIT: Ok, so apparently you have to have a keyboard that has a "Break" key on it in order to even find where the error is. Wow. Fortunately I happen to have one. Here's the code that Access takes me to if I press `break` when I see the error message. This code is for a subform of another form. It highlights the first line (Private Sub Form_Current()).

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If NumEnums > 0 Then
        CurrentEnum = val(Nz(bit_value_edit.value)) 'Update CurrentEnum to the currently selected enum
        Call UpdateEnumsLabel(Me.Parent![enums label]) 'Update label
    End If
End Sub
```

...and here's UpdateEnumsLabel():

```vb
Public Sub UpdateEnumsLabel(ByRef label As Control)
    If NumEnums > 0 Then
        label.Caption = "Enums: " & CurrentEnum & "/" & NumEnums
    Else
        label.Caption = "Enums: 0"
    End If
End Sub
```

The definition for CurrentEnum:

```vb
Public CurrentEnum, CurrentPort, CurrentFile, CurrentGroup As Long
```

I'm thinking that this error is unrelated to the code in Form_Current(), but Access is highlighting that line because the error happens when the form is opened. But the form doesn't contain anything that uses a query, so I'm confused as to what query Access has a problem with.

Comment: exactly what line is highlighted? Also is CurrentENum a fucntion? And what does the UpdateEnumsLabels function do?

Comment: @DougCoats I added that info to the question.

Comment: Examine named queries and/or `SELECT` statements which are used as the form's record source or as row source for combo or list boxes.  If the form includes a subform, repeat those examinations there.  Please show us the full text of the error message.

Comment: @HansUp I looked at all the record sources/row sources for the form, and none of them use any SQL. The form only contains labels and textboxes that will be used later.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error message (just add the imgur.com link to your question).

Comment: @Andre https://imgur.com/a/PesjIFk

Comment: Yes, the VBA code is probably not the issue. But if the form has a `Current` event, it is bound, so it has a record source. Unless that's a plain table, there is your SQL (either directly or in the query) that you should check.

Comment: @Andre The record source is blank, though. Could the SQL error be in the parent form?

Comment: Then it's set by VBA code, either in Form_Load/_Open or in the parent form.

Answer (score 1):

When the error Message pops up, Use Control+Break. It will take you to the line causes the issue.

You should also open a module and form the debug option in the VBA editor select "Compile All Modules"

And since it appears to happening on open/load, you can check both the macros and the main modules to find anything that triggers on AutoExec.

Comment: This takes me to some code that doesn't have any errors. It compiles fine. There's also no SQL statements near the code it takes me to, so that can't be the right location. I wish Access would just tell me what file and line the issue is at...

Comment: @DanielCourtney-Gregerson What is the code it takes you too? This will help me help you how to trouble shoot more

Comment: I added the code to the question because it wouldn't format properly as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Often ctrl-break will hit the line where you errored out. However, in the case of multiple “events”, and code without error handling, then often the error occurs in the routine that called the code, not the actual code that caused the error.

What I would do launch the application (hold down the shift key to prevent any start up code, or forms running).

Now that you launched the application, but without forms or code running, then check for an autoexecc macro (if there is one, check what code it attempts to run).

If there not an autoexec macro in use, then check under file->options->current database. In this view, you can look/see/determine what the name of the start-up form is.

Once you determined the start-up form (or start up module/code) called from autoexec macro, then you can simply add a blank code module, and place in your code the SAME command that is used to start your application.

So let’s assume no autoexec macro, and you determine that the start-up form is frmMain.

So now, we can launch the application (hold down shift key to prevent any start up code from running). Now, type into a new “test” standard code module the following code:

```
Sub MyGo

  Stop

  Docmd.OpenForm "frmMain"

End sub
```

So you type in above code, hit ctrl-s to save the above code. Now with your cursor anyplace inside of the above code, you simply hit F5 to run.

At this point you hit/stop on the “stop” command in the debugger. At this point, you then can hit f8 to step to the next line of code. If the form in question calls other code etc., you still be able to single step, and “eventually” you hit the line which causes the error.

While the application may be large, a simple look at the start up forms (and huts then the start-up code) means that you ONLY really need to trace and look at the start up code – not the whole application.